# How to reset only the database entries for a specific theme?

Tags: database, wordpress, wordpress-theming, reset

I ran into a bug while modifying a WordPress theme. The bug is that on Firefox, the page is scrollable to extremely many pixels, even though the actual website content is the proper size.

I also tried deleting both the parent and child themes, reinstalled them using the original zip files, but it doesn't work because the settings are actually saved in a database.

(I know this to be true because the custom color settings I chose reappear even after deleting and reinstalling the themes. If this is the case, does that mean the problem is not caused by my tampering with the CSS, but through a setting that is customizable from the WordPress customize interface?)

I haven't been able to find the code I tampered with manually, so I want to reset the database without resetting ALL the database settings. I just want to reset the database for the theme I tampered with.

How to reset the database for only a given theme, not the entire database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the following functions used in the theme:

- `add_option( 'option_name', $values );`
- `update_option( 'option_name', $values );`

Then search the database for `option_name` and delete the entries. If you are lucky, the theme uses only one entry and saves everything inside an array (`$values`). But there are themes that save each value inside one option, something like:

```
$values = array(
    'color' => '#fff', 
    'background' => '#000', 
    'etc' => 'something',
    // a hundred more options
);
$theme_prefix = 'superTheme_';
foreach( $values as $value => $default ) {
    add_option( $theme_prefix . $value, $default );
}
```